# Comparing strings in a list

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm trying to filter out search results from an API by trying to find and exclude dictionary entries which have 'affiliation names' which are all the same.

To cut a long story short, in the code below, entry2 is a list of 20 dictionaries all of which have nested dictionaries within them, one of which is 'affiliation'. Within this nested dictionary 'affiliation' for each element of entry2, I want to compare the 'affilnames' and if they are not all equal pass the entry2 dictionary element in question to a new list, entry3.

So far, I have the following (since all entry2 dictionaries only have 2 list elements within 'affiliation'):

```
entry3 = [s for s in entry2 if s['affiliation'][0]['affilname'] != s['affiliation'][1]['affilname']]
```

which works fine (and returns entry3 having 9 dictionary entries). However, it may not always be the case that there are only 2 list entries within 'affiliation' and so I want to find a way to compare all of the strings within 'affiliation'. I have the following line of code which logically makes sense to me but is returning entry3 as having the same number of dictionary elements as entry2:

```
entry3 = [s for s in entry2 if any(s['affiliation'][i]['affilname'] for i in range(1,len(s['affiliation'])-1)) != s['affiliation'][0]['affilname']]
```

Can anyone help me with what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Readability!!! As long as you write unreadable code, you will keep having problems... This line deserves splitting into at least three separate lines. Cache `foo=s['affiliation']`, then use `any(bar['affilname'] for bar in foo[1:-1])` instead of `range()` etc. Then the error will be easy to spot. Of course do not use `foo` and `bar` but choose some meaningful names... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *filter* condition of your *list comprehension* is not properly structured. `any` returns a boolean which you're comparing with the `affilname` entry - a string. That would return all the entries since a string will never be equal to a boolean.

You can instead check if there is any entry with `affilname` subdict that is not the matching the first `affilname` in that category/sub-dict level:

```
entry3 = [s for s in entry2 if any(dct['affilname'] != s['affiliation'][0]['affilname'] for dct in s['affiliation'])]
```

Once there is a mismatch at that subdict level, any *breaks* and returns `True`, which will add that entry to `entry3`

Comment: @RThompson I made a fix on the indexing. Pls take note